# Open context menu when user clicks on option menu item

Tags: android, contextmenu

i want to open context menu when user selects the option menu item.but `registerForContextMenu();` takes view object.is there any way to open context menu when user select option menuitem?

Comment: Are you trying to open actionbar menu when the user selects the option menu on device or you want to open any context menu when option button on phone is tapped

Comment: You have the `openContextMenu()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : create the ContextMenu methods

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Step 2 : create your dialog

```
CharSequence[] items = {"item1","item2","item3"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Options");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            }
        }).show();
```